# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression for Oracle but not valid for MySQL in context of clause difference

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I have run this query in Oracle

```
select studentid, attndmark
from attendance_master m,
     attendance_detail d
where m.attnid = d.attendid
group by studentid
```

and got the error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

The error is fine and I know the issue of column list in select clause. But similar query is valid in MySQL.

```
SELECT aff.akey, username
FROM `affiliates` aff,
     affstats ast
WHERE aff.akey = ast.akey
group by aff.akey
```

I need a query trick that can run on both RDBMS Oracle/ Mysql and also MSSQL.

What could be the trick?

Comment: If there are several rows with the same aff.akey having different username values, how do chose which one to return?

Comment: I don't believe that this question was not asked until today on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL is wrong, in the sense that it does not conform to the SQL standard (or even common sense in this case).  It allows columns in the `SELECT` that are not arguments to aggregation functions and that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  The documentation is explicit that the values come from "indeterminate" rows.

By the way, you should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The query can be written as:

```
SELECT aff.akey, MAX(username)
FROM affiliates aff JOIN
     affstats ast 
     ON aff.akey=ast.akey
GROUP BY aff.akey;
```

This will work in both databases.

Comment: Whats logic of max func here?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam . . . It chooses an "arbitrary" value of `username`.